# Issue with JBOSS CDI for Odata4J

Tags: jboss, cdi, resteasy, wildfly-8, odata4j

I am trying to deploy   OData4j in wildfly server . At the startup of the application I am getting the following error,

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException: WELD-001437: Normal scoped bean class org.odata4j.producer.resources.DefaultODataProducerProvider is not proxyable because the type is final or it contains a final method protected final org.odata4j.producer.ODataProducer org.odata4j.producer.resources.DefaultODataProducerProvider.newProducerFromFactory(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties) - <unknown javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean instance>.
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableClassException(Proxies.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableTypeException(Proxies.java:178)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableTypeException(Proxies.java:140)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:736)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:762)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.getReference(ForwardingBeanManager.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.getReference(BeanManagerProxy.java:89)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiConstructorInjector.construct(CdiConstructorInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.addContextResolver(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1637)
    ... 20 more
```

Is there any workaround to get rid of this issue. 
Please suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exact version of Wildfly are you using?

Comment: I am using Wildfly8.2.0.